# getting TypeError: slice indices must be integers

Tags: python, typeerror

I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\Python\driving-lane-departure-warning-master\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    img_aug = process_frame(img)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\Python\driving-lane-departure-warning-master\lane.py", line 612, in process_frame
    output = create_output_frame(offcenter, pts, img_undist_, fps, curvature, curve_direction, binary_sub)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\Python\driving-lane-departure-warning-master\lane.py", line 484, in create_output_frame
    whole_frame[220+h/2:220+2*h/2, 20:20+w/2, :] = undist_birdview
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove this error ?

Here is the piece of the code:

```
def create_output_frame(offcenter, pts, undist_ori, fps, curvature, curve_direction, binary_sub, threshold=0.6):
    """
    :param offcenter:
    :param pts:
    :param undist_ori:
    :param fps:
    :param threshold:
    :return:
    """

    undist_ori = cv2.resize(undist_ori, (0,0), fx=1/output_frame_scale, fy=1/output_frame_scale)
    w = undist_ori.shape[1]
    h = undist_ori.shape[0]

    undist_birdview = warper(cv2.resize(undist_ori, (0,0), fx=1/2, fy=1/2), M_b)

    color_warp = np.zeros_like(undist_ori).astype(np.uint8)

    # create a frame to hold every image
    whole_frame = np.zeros((h*3,w*3, 3), dtype=np.uint8)


    if abs(offcenter) > threshold:  # car is offcenter more than 0.6 m
        # Draw Red lane
        cv2.fillPoly(color_warp, np.int_([pts]), (255, 0, 0)) # red
    else: # Draw Green lane
        cv2.fillPoly(color_warp, np.int_([pts]), (0,255, 0))  # green

    newwarp = cv2.warpPerspective(color_warp, M_inv, (int(frame_width/input_scale), int(frame_height/input_scale)))

    # Combine the result with the original image    # result = cv2.addWeighted(undist, 1, newwarp, 0.3, 0)

    newwarp_ = cv2.resize(newwarp,None, fx=input_scale/output_frame_scale, fy=input_scale/output_frame_scale, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    output = cv2.addWeighted(undist_ori, 1, newwarp_, 0.3, 0)

    ############## generate the combined output frame only for visualization purpose ################
    whole_frame[40:40+h, 20:20+w, :] = undist_ori
    whole_frame[40:40+h, 60+w:60+2*w, :] = output
    whole_frame[220+h/2:220+2*h/2, 20:20+w/2, :] = undist_birdview
    whole_frame[220+h/2:220+2*h/2, 40+w/2:40+w, 0] = cv2.resize((binary_sub*255).astype(np.uint8), (0,0), fx=1/2, fy=1/2)
    whole_frame[220+h/2:220+2*h/2, 40+w/2:40+w, 1] = cv2.resize((binary_sub*255).astype(np.uint8), (0,0), fx=1/2, fy=1/2)
    whole_frame[220+h/2:220+2*h/2, 40+w/2:40+w, 2] = cv2.resize((binary_sub*255).astype(np.uint8), (0,0), fx=1/2, fy=1/2)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    if offcenter >= 0:
        offset = offcenter
        direction = 'Right'
    elif offcenter < 0:
        offset = -offcenter
        direction = 'Left'

    info_road = "Road Status"
    info_lane = "Lane info: {0}".format(curve_direction)
    info_cur = "Curvature {:6.1f} m".format(curvature)
    info_offset = "Off center: {0} {1:3.1f}m".format(direction, offset)
    info_framerate = "{0:4.1f} fps".format(fps)
    info_warning = "Warning: offcenter > 0.6m (use higher threshold in real life)"

    cv2.putText(whole_frame, "Departure Warning System with a Monocular Camera", (23,25), font, 0.8, (255,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, "Origin", (22,70), font, 0.6, (255,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, "Augmented", (40+w+25,70), font, 0.6, (255,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, "Bird's View", (22+30,70+35+h), font, 0.6, (255,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, "Lanes", (22+225,70+35+h), font, 0.6, (255,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, info_road, (40+w+50,70+35+h), font, 0.8, (255,255,0), 1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, info_warning, (35+w,60+h), font, 0.4, (255,255,0), 1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, info_lane, (40+w+50,70+35+40+h), font, 0.8, (255,255,0), 1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, info_cur, (40+w+50,70+35+80+h), font, 0.8, (255,255,0), 1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, info_offset, (40+w+50,70+35+120+h), font, 0.8, (255,255,0), 1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(whole_frame, info_framerate, (40+w+250,70), font, 0.6, (255,255,0), 1,cv2.LINE_AA)

    return whole_frame
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Python are you using?
There is a possibility that the problem is in division by 2.
Try to replace "h/2" and "w/2" with "h//2" and "w//2" respectively.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time. I solved this issue. It was due to problem in Division.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the slice indices are float or double or if the syntax of slicing is incorrect.Check the slicing syntax or type of the slice indices.

Possible error cases:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a = a[1.2:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

a = a[1,2:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

a = a[1:2,3:4,:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```